# Display value in view

Tags: codeigniter

In this codeigniter model i have this query testing if value entered in input exists in database..

```
 function get_search_form() {
     $match = $this->input->post('search1');
     $this->db->where('numero',$match);
     $this->db->where('inscris','non');
     $q = $this->db->get('transaction');
     if($q->num_rows()>0)
      {
      foreach($q->result() as $row)
      {
        $data[] = $row;
      }
       return $data;
     }
}
```

Behold the controller i'd like to display value grabbed in input in view inscription.php

```
  function search()
  {
    $data['row'] = $this->site_model->get_search_form();
    $this->load->view('acceuil/aside');
    $this->load->view('acceuil/inscription', $data);
  }
```

My issue is how to display in that view  input value and a form if this value exists in database ?
  I have tried like this but i need help :

inscription view:

```
<?=form_open('navigation/search');?>

<input type="text" name="search1" id="search1" required />
<input type='submit' value='Display' /> 
<?=form_close();?>
```

I try to display the form like this but i don't know how to display as well the input value entered

```
  <?php
     if( $row > 0 )
     {
  ?>
  les champs du formulaire ici....
  <?php 
     }else
      { }
   ?>
```

Comment: You are returning an *array* of rows.  In your view, `$row` is an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view you can check if the variable `$row` is not null (because it will be null when no rows are found):

```
if ($row !== null) {
  // do stuff
}
```

You can modify the model function to return some other value if no rows are found, for example, by setting the $data to an empty array:

```
function get_search_form() {
     $match = $this->input->post('search1');
     $this->db->where('numero',$match);
     $this->db->where('inscris','non');
     $q = $this->db->get('transaction');
     $data = array();  // <--- here
     if($q->num_rows()>0)
      {
      foreach($q->result() as $row)
      {
        $data[] = $row;
      }
       return $data;
     }
}
```

And then in the view you can simply loop the data:

```
foreach($row as $r) {
  // do stuff
}
```

or you can implode the array to use as the input value:

```
<input type="text" 
       name="search1" 
       id="search1" required 
       value="<?php echo implode(' ', $row); ?>" />
```

You could also use html entities here, in case double quotes are possible to appear in what your model function returns (I have no idea what it returns).

Comment: thanks for yours codes everything is almost fine, now i need only to display the $row content like echo $row...

Comment: You're welcome, you can use what I put into the input value: `<?php echo implode(' ', $row); ?>` you can't just `echo $row;` because it's an array.

Comment: when i add it i have this message : Message: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: Did you set it to be an array? If you followed my instructions, that message shouldn't appear at all.

Comment: i add  this line in mdel as you said:$data = array(); i think we sould add or change something in the controller as well..

Comment: Ah, one more thing - the return statement needs to be outside of the if block - it should be the very last line of the function. Otherwise, the function will still return null if no rows are found.

Comment: when i use if $row there is no error but when i user foreach($row as $r) there is this: Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()...Sorry i'm not so good at codeigniter !

Comment: Read my previous comment - `return $data;` needs to be the last line of the model function. See this: http://ideone.com/DUaYeU  See how it throws no errors neither for implode, nor for foreach.

Comment: i see exemple, but according to what i learn you call a model function in a controller, and you display the view in the controller. i think the model would be in the controller like this :      function search()
{

   $data['row'] = $this->model_name->get_search_form();

$this->load->view('acceuil/inscription', $data);
}                                                                                                                  Sorry if can't understand quickly

Answer (score 0):

you can access $data global object like this check

```
<?php
     if( isset($row))
     {
         foreach($row as $v){
            //Do the operations here
         }     
     }else
      { 
          //Do the operations here
      }
?>
```